# Excessive stack depth comparing types

Tags: typescript

Why is the following erroring, and how does one solve it?

```js
type Lookup<T, K extends keyof any, Else = never> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : Else
type Fn = (input: any) => any

type ReverseTuple<
  T extends [any, ...any[]],
  NewArray extends any[] = [],
  First = T extends [infer F, ...any] ? F : never,
  Rest extends [any, ...any[]] = T extends [any, ...infer R extends [any, ...any[]]] ? R : never,
> = [Rest] extends [never] ? [First, ...NewArray] : ReverseTuple<Rest, [First, ...NewArray]>

type LinkedFn<
  F1 extends Fn,
  F2 extends Fn,
  RT = (input: ReturnType<F1>) => ReturnType<F2>,
> = RT extends Fn ? RT : never

type FunctionChainArray<
  T extends [Fn, ...Fn[]],
  First extends Fn = T extends [infer F extends Fn, ...any] ? F : never,
  ModdedT extends Fn[] = [(Input: any) => Parameters<First>[0], ...T],
  Res = { [K in keyof T]: LinkedFn<Lookup<ModdedT, K>, T[K]> },
  RT extends [Fn, ...Fn[]] = Res extends [...infer A extends [Fn, ...Fn[]]] ? A : never, // hack
> = RT

function compositor<T extends [Fn, ...Fn[]]>(
  ...functions: T & ReverseTuple<T> extends [Fn, ...Fn[]]
    ? ReverseTuple<FunctionChainArray<ReverseTuple<T>>>
    : never
) {
  return functions as unknown as ReverseTuple<T> extends [Fn, ...Fn[]]
    ? ReverseTuple<FunctionChainArray<ReverseTuple<T>>>
    : never
}
const y2 = compositor(
  (a: 'Rb') => 'Rb' as 'Rb',
  (a: 'Ra') => 'Rb' as 'Rb',
  (a: 'start') => 'Ra' as 'Ra',
)
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9nA1gVzAHgCoBooGkoQAewEAdgCYDOUiEIcAZlAIakg4CiANpdALxRSEAG4QATgD4oA-ERIVqtekwxQA-FAwBtXAF0oALijdeAKFCQoAMVLSoACgCWpMMmBHWIAJTSpn0+bg0ABKIuK8GKhcEGimUJoExGRUUFqeOAB0WZ5aurpYcVAAchAA7gCCYmLMIInyKTn6ArkF8VaOYpTAdqpyydRazgzi1pnZbPoaVoaCYWKtUKFddf2p6VBZGY1NCX0Ka2xjGUMjwSv7aYcb4yC5eeqLM0Ki86ZSzUvA+nspWs-ik1S7U6wCOJQqVRq+iMoReESiMU+OC0wK6YLKlWqIF0EgCFmgMGctHINlibQAjOcUjYFlYAExU6g0wrBVQCJwuNwwiDAZBiUgYIJoKzkiQ+PhSUK8-mCyDCukSArvRa9JL7GwPVlPOZ4oLWZCkADGwEccFIAGEABbMZyYmpk3Zq34064ZGx3WkdZY-Jm2ASq+oDE5iayM6ykI6eQHTIz-V7xACycHI5Ag5ADq3dOy09gAkpz3Cw2OKpAAFZjVAC2PPCwq9wAkWgADPlXRh8iyINQBABvVL4Zw0OiMTS6IyE0jE0nwJCoNBJlNp7B4RWaHQ4qAAXwWWp9QIjrqzOyWYa0m2DUHKp5dmyPgKvsbmOAA9M+oNbDYg3nZWQEGAbjVNWxDTgSswDgShHGAOAxEwa8D1vUg7gkexCk2f8jRNM1KCMVQADJFjmeEwGiTApD3FEEKyI9CniDRYXCCBIhImIrAArCLWtW1IRANAGM6JiETIiRcXieJHxeUwfB7QoxB5PlbAwwDsJYagDUQUg4FKWxmGofjiNIjByKdAYb2opC8lozUiMEljhXYoCrRtUg7V4-TbMMkTRLEiTxFMTdTBA0hlhABkBBAsCIKgmDUPiexmCMAByYIACNEpLKBkrS1TMtSxKFnipLgmYdLfFy7LdPK-LCkKzKugrYBSolXKSpy5KSoKLwgA)

Comment: You can check [my article](https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose) about function composition. Also, please check links at the and of an article

Comment: @captain-yossarian thank you - a useful resource.  I have already solved the typing for function composition and that works.  However here I'm allowing one to add functions in reverse order - and that's the only change and is what's causing the problem - i.e. `ReverseTuple` is breaking the typing for some unknown reason.

Comment: @captain-yossarian  [here](https://tsplay.dev/NlLxON) is my working composition code - only change in my question is `ReverseTuple`

Comment: @captain-yossarian - I suspect the problem is the recursion in ReverseTuple doesn't play nice with the compiler - and so I suspect this is a bug, I was hoping someone knows some kind of workaround.

Comment: @caTS, you seem to be the person who understands the typesccript compiler best, and so if I may  be so bold as to please ask you to have a look at this and see if you know of any solutions?

Comment: I have simplified a `ReverseTuple` utility type a bit. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/mqeQRm) . I don't understand what `FunctionChainArray` does.

Comment: @captain-yossarian thank you so much - that fixed the problem completely and now it works!  One can chain functions in reverse order!  I'd love to understand why my version didn't work though.